# VB6 ActiveX DLL - Public Declare Lib

Tags: dll, vb6, activex, declare

I have a line of code I need to compile into a (ActiveX) DLL in VB6, unfortunately I am always greeted with a, "Declare statements not allowed as public members of object modules".

The line looks like this:

```
Public Declare Sub Example Lib "kernel32"
```

Is there any work around? I saw somewhere you can do this with, `Property Set`, or `Property Let`. I'm just not sure how. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you:

```
Private Declare Sub Example Lib "kernel32"

Public Sub CallExample() 
   Call Example
End Sub
```

Here is a MSFT reference that gives more info:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278767.aspx

Comment: The wrapper should be a method, not a property.  Note that the Declare doesn't return a value anyway, so your example makes no sense.

Comment: +1 Although I have taken the liberty of editing your answer in accordance with Bob77's comment. Nice link.